# How to convert column value to CamelCase with Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, camelcasing

I need a way to convert a column value to CamelCase with Oracle 10g. I prefer to do it in-line with my select statement but if I have to use a function, that is OK too.

I don't need to support underscores, just spaces.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If you have stored a value in, say, all lower case in a table, how would any function know how to convert that into CamelCase?  That function, at a minimum, would need to have a dictionary of all the available words in order to figure out that the string `camelcase` should be converted into `CamelCase`.  And if any of the words in your string are not dictionary words, life gets more challenging.

Comment: @JustinCave: You really didn't understand the question :-) "camel case" -> "CamelCase". Note the space between "camel" and "case". That's the indicator.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no built in function that does this. What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: OK.  So is your intention that you simply remove every space from the string and capitalize the first character of the string along with any letter that followed a space?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, yes you are right. "camel case" -> "CamelCase" is what I am trying to achieve. I am aware that there is no built in function, so I am looking for a way to do it... I have tried a couple of things but it is getting messy and was hoping for something cleaner

Comment: @JustinCave, yes that's the idea. Capitalize the first letter of the string.. capitalize every letter following a space and un-capitalize (lower-case) all other characters...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I guess a combination of [`initcap()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/initcap.php) and [`replace()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php) would work:

```
select replace(initcap('hi ben'),' ') from dual;

REPLA
-----
HiBen
```

This simply capitalises the first character of every word and then replaces the spaces with nothing.

It obviously won't work if the first character is numeric:

```
select replace(initcap('go 2stack overflow'),' ') from dual;

REPLACE(INITCAP(
----------------
Go2stackOverflow
```

Comment: That is AWESOME! I wasn't aware of the initcap built-in function! Works like charm... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

That's not my understanding of camelCase

```
select substr(lower('Camel Case means the first char should be lower cased'),1,1)||substr(replace(initcap('Camel Case means the first char should be lower cased'),' '),2) from dual;
```

```
camelCaseMeansTheFirstCharShouldBeLowerCased                                    
1 row selected.
```

Comment: CamelCase could also be the first letter. Now some write variables with a lower case first letter.